# How to extract a value from [DDXMLElement] in Swift?

Tags: swift, xml

I want to extract the value of id in the stanza tag.
The stanza tag is:

```
[<stanza-id xmlns="urn:xmpp:sid:0" by="f.talebi@wepod.ir" id="1531235744929009"></stanza-id>]
```

This is a part of message received from Xmpp server.
 I need to extract "1531235744929009" value. Therefore, I wrote this:

```
var stanza = message.elements(forName: "stanza-id")
print(stanza)
var id = stanza.first?.attributes
if let attributes = stanza.first?.attributes {
     let lastItem = attributes.last
     if let stanzaID = lastItem?.stringValue {
          print("stanzaID = \(stanzaID)")
     }
}
```

This code works correctly, but its not a clean code. especially where I wrote this line `lastItem = attributes.last` because if the order changes this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

just use `stanza.attributed(forName: String)`